# Add outward curving border to elements like this: ◝◟___◞◜

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

### Problem

My navbar looks like this:

[image]

**HTML** and **CSS**

```css
nav {
  width: 1040px;
}
nav ul {
  display: block;
  list-style-type: none;
  height: 40px;
  border-top: 3px solid #222;
}
nav ul li {
  width: 130px;
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: Vollkorn;
  font-weight: 400;
}
nav ul li a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #333;
}
nav ul li a:hover,
nav ul li a:focus {
  color: #000;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px black;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 2px solid #222;
  border-top: 0px;
  transition: 0.2s ease all;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Random</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Blog</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">About us</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Contact Us</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

### Desired Output

In the above picture, the list item **blog** is focused or hovered. In hover style, it has a border-radius of 5px. The problem is that I want the *top left and right corners*, when hovered, to curve outwards like this :

[image]

I am able to achieve this result using background image, and also using position styles and z-index. I wanted a CSS **border-only** solution.

### P.S.

The desired output may look undesirable (at least to me), but I just wanted to know if this could be done.

Comment: How about a javascript solution? Put border radius on prev/next element + current one.

Comment: @Vucko but then the output will be effected. If we put border radius on prev and next list item, then we'll have to put border right on prev and border left on next element. In both cases, a part of border of prev and next li's will get extended and generate an even uglier output. Position will have to be used.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the top of my head: draw bottom half border on the element and draw top-left and top-right borders on positioned pseudo elements.

```css
/* using 4px border, 1em border radius, 1em padding */
nav ul {
  font: medium sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  border-top: 4px solid;
}
nav li {
  display: inline-block;
  border-left: 4px solid transparent;
  border-right: 4px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 4px solid transparent;
  border-radius: 0 0 1em 1em;
  padding: 0 1em 1em;
  position: relative;
  top: 1em;
}
nav li:before,
nav li:after {
  display: none;
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: -1em;
  width: 1em;
  height: 1em;
  margin-top: -4px;
}
nav li:before {
  right: 100%;
  border-top: 4px solid;
  border-right: 4px solid;
  border-top-right-radius: 1em;
}
nav li:after {
  left: 100%;
  border-top: 4px solid;
  border-left: 4px solid;
  border-top-left-radius: 1em;
}
nav li:hover {
  border-color: initial;
}
nav li:hover:before,
nav li:hover:after {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li>Home</li>
    <li>Random</li>
    <li>Blog</li>
    <li>About us</li>
    <li>Contact Us</li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: I see, you've also used positioning. Isn't it possible with just border? I have achieved this result with background image and also with positioning. I wanted a border only solution. (+1) For effort.

Comment: Sorry, could not think of any border only solution (there is no negative border radius).

Comment: Maybe it's not possible. Firstly negative borders don't work and secondly, if there were negative borders, they would take the area of neighbouring sibling **list items**, thus dislocating them and generating an ugly output. The only solutions that I think are possible are positioning, z-index, and background image. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: There are exotic CSS3 solutions such as border-image and SVG backgrounds. In fact, SVG images will let you do very unusual things, but browser support is questionable and my SVG knowledge is insufficient.

Comment: Others (Terry and Kroltan) too have used pseudoelements and positioning to get the result. I think its the only usable method.

Comment: svg browser support is questionable? No its not! The only browser its not supported in is IE8.

Answer (score 3):

I have a rather *hacky* solution, if you want to call it as such. It is a use of both `::before` and `::after` pseudo elements to create invisible rectangles on the top left and right corners of the active link (hovered or in focus), with the border radius set at the correct edge.

```css
nav {
  width: 1040px;
}
nav ul {
  display: block;
  list-style-type: none;
  height: 40px;
  border-top: 3px solid #222;
}
nav ul li {
  width: 130px;
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 30px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: Vollkorn;
  font-weight: 400;
}
nav ul li a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #333;
  position: relative;
}
nav ul li a::before, nav ul li a::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-top: 2px solid #000;
  content: '';
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: -12px;
  width: 12px;
  height: 12px;
}
nav ul li a::before {
  border-top-right-radius: 10px;
  border-right: 2px solid #000;
  right: 100%;
}
nav ul li a::after {
  border-top-left-radius: 10px;
  border-left: 2px solid #000;
  left: 100%;
}
nav ul li a:hover,
nav ul li a:focus {
  color: #000;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
  border: 2px solid #222;
  border-top: none;
}
nav ul li a:hover::before, nav ul li a:hover::after,
nav ul li a:focus::before, nav ul li a:focus::after {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Random</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Blog</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">About us</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Contact Us</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Thanks for your effort (+1), but I already have done this with pseudo elements and positioning. (Also with background image). I know it works, but I wanted a border-only solution.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's quite possible:

```css
#a{
    margin-top: 25px;
    position: relative;
    overflow: visible;
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-align: center;
    border: 3px solid black;
    border-top: none;
    border-radius: 0 0 25px 25px;
    margin-left: 25px;
    height: 50px;
}
#a, #a:after, #a:before{
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: inline-block;
}
#a:after, #a:before{
    position: absolute;
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    content: ".";
    color: transparent;
    border: 3px solid black;
    border-bottom: none;
    top: -25px;
}
#a:before{
    border-left: none;
    border-top-right-radius: 25px;
    left: -25px;
}
#a:after{
    border-right: none;
    border-top-left-radius: 25px;
    right: -25px;
}
```

```html
<div id="a">Hello</div>
```

Or simplifying the style sheet with LESS:

```
#a {
    @round-width: 25px;
    @border-style: 3px solid black;

    @offset: -@round-width;

    &, &:after, &:before {
        box-sizing: border-box;
        display: inline-block;
    }

    position: relative;
    overflow: visible;
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-align: center;
    border: @border-style;
    border-top: none;
    border-radius: 0 0 @round-width @round-width;
    margin-left: @round-width;
    height: 50px;

    &:after, &:before {
        position: absolute;
        width: @round-width;
        height: @round-width;
        color: transparent;
        content: ".";
        border: @border-style;
        border-bottom: none;
        top: @offset;
    }

    &:before {
        border-left: none;
        border-top-right-radius: @round-width;
        left: @offset;
    }
    &:after {
        border-right: none;
        border-top-left-radius: @round-width;
        right: @offset;
    }
}
```

Nice thing of LESS is that you only mention the base selector (`#a`) once, and so for the widths.

Comment: You used position again. I think its not possible with only border-radius. btw is it easier and quicker to use LESS than plain CSS? I never tried to learn it as I thought I'll have to learn new semantics. (+1) For effort :)

Comment: @ThePragmatick Don't think it's possible if you want to use only one tag per tab.. About LESS, I find it a wonderfully simple abstraction of CSS, much similar to my mind model of a great styling language