# Border radius of complex shape

Tags: css

I am trying to get the following shape as css. Anybody help me to get any kind of tutorial or code snippet of how to having this king of shape as css?

[image]

Comment: Related (or possible duplicate of) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27676867/add-outward-curving-border-to-elements-like-this (the outward curve part of the shape)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need a few extra elements two create the thingies on the left and right.

Note: this works only on a solid background (in this case the white background used on `.ws_left:before` and `.ws_right:before`

```css
body { margin: 5em; }
.ws {
  position: relative;
  width: 15em;
  height: 15em;
  background: gray;
  border-radius: 0 0 1em 1em;
}
.ws_left {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: -4em;
  right: 100%;
  height: 2.5em;
  background: gray;
  border-radius: 1em 0 0 1em;
}
  .ws_left:before, .ws_left:after,
  .ws_right:before, .ws_right:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    background: red;
    width: 1em;
    height: 1em;
    top: 100%;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 1;
  }
  .ws_left:before {
    border-top-right-radius: 1em;
    background: white;
    z-index: 2;
  }
  .ws_left:after {
    background: gray;
  }

  .ws_right:before, .ws_right:after {
    right: auto;
    left: 0;
  }
  .ws_right:before {
    border-top-left-radius: 1em;
    background: white;
    z-index: 2;
  }
  .ws_right:after {
    background: gray;
  }
.ws_right {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 100%;
  right: -2em;
  height: 2.5em;
  background: gray;
  border-radius: 0 1em 1em 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="ws">
  <div class="ws_left"></div>
  <div class="ws_right"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. two radius is missing. That is the toughest part for me.

Answer (score 2):

I hope it will be helpfully for you:-

```css
.maindiv{ background:#4C4B4B; width:400px; height:330px; border-radius:12px; position:relative; margin:auto;}
.maindiv::after {
  background: #4c4b4b none repeat scroll 0 0;
  border-radius: 25px 0 0 25px;
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  height: 50px;
  left: -90px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
}
.maindiv::before {
  background: #4c4b4b none repeat scroll 0 0;
  border-radius: 0 25px 25px 0;
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  height: 50px;
  right: -90px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
}
#simulated {
  left: -30px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 29px;
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
  z-index: 9999;
}
#simulated2 {
  right: -30px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 29px;
  transform: rotate(161deg);
  z-index: 9999;
}
#simulated path, #simulated2 path {
  fill:#4c4b4b;
}
```

```html
<div class="maindiv">
<svg width="60" height="60" id="simulated">
 <path d="M 40 0 h 320 a 40 30 0 0 0 40 30 v 240 a 40 30 0 0 0 -40 30 h -320 a 40 30 0 0 0 -40 -30 v -240 a 40 30 0 0 0 40 -30 Z"/>
</svg>
<svg width="60" height="60" id="simulated2">
 <path d="M 40 0 h 320 a 40 30 0 0 0 40 30 v 240 a 40 30 0 0 0 -40 30 h -320 a 40 30 0 0 0 -40 -30 v -240 a 40 30 0 0 0 40 -30 Z"/>
</svg>
</div>
```